# Providing aliases to Parent class data array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Probably not the wisest choice, but modelling a `Vertex<T, N>` class to abstract `Vertex2<T>`, `Vertex3<T>` and `Vertex4<T>` implementations, providing basic access. It's structured like this:

```
template<typename T, unsigned N>
class _Vertex {
    const unsigned _size = N;
    T _data[N];

public:
    inline _Vertex() : _data() {};

    inline T const& operator[](int pos) const { return _data[pos]; } 
    inline T      & operator[](int pos)       { return _data[pos]; }
};
```

Say I want to implement `Vertex2<T>` as a `Vertex<T, 2>`, and provide aliases like `x` and `y`. The most proper way would be adding functions like:

```
 inline T const& x() const { return (*this)[0]; }
 inline T      & x()       { return (*this)[0]; }
```

This would be repeated for every property, or alias I'd like to add. It's not a bad design, but usage proves tricky as, provided `v` is of type `Vector2<float>`, `v.x() = 1.0f` is not as friendly as `v.x = 1.0f`.

Is there any way to provide clearer, friendlier alias?

My main thoughts were "abusing" memory layout, providing access to `_data[i]` accordingly, but I have no idea where to start.

This question is based on my "re-imagination" of a `vertex.h` header file provided for an assigment, so this makes it related to homework, but I can assure you the end is not. It's just my curiosity holding me off doing my homework!

Comment: `_size` should be `static` to avoid issues with the assignment operator. You should probably also make it `constexpr`.

Comment: regardless of the question, you want to mark your `operator []` as `noexcept` as it never throws an exception

Comment: A way to add data members is to make specializations for `_Vertex<1>` to `_Vertex<3>`. That would have the added benefit that `_Vertex<1>` doesn't have a member `y`. But it is probably not worth the code duplication required to make it work.

Comment: Unrelated: Careful with names like `_Vertex`. Underscore followed by Capital Letter is reserved for use by the library. More here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: @nwp I guessed, and actually implemented it at first. It makes more sense, too, as every vector of the class would have the same length/size

Comment: @David Haim why that? Can you elaborate, maybe with a link?

Comment: @user4581301 so, should I change it to lowercase? I was thinking of underscoring the "private" ones and not underscoring the "public" ones (shown with using statements)

Comment: Use something other than an underscore or stick the underscore at the end. Read the link and you'll see there are a whole bunch of rules. At global scope `_vertex` is reserved, but if you pop it in a namespace you're good. Underscore+Capital can get you at any scope as can two underscores in a row anywhere in an identifier. Personally, I just never use a preceding underscore rather than try to remember exactly when I can and cannot use one.

Comment: @user4581301 I'd use namespaces, so I guess I'd be good. I don't quite like "tail" underscores, as an IDE can pop them up, while a "head" underscore would not. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put on my robe and Yakk hat.

`operator->*` is clearly underutilized in C++. We can overload to take a tag type of our choosing in a way that kind of looks like member access. Here's a simplified example:

```
template <size_t I> struct index_t { };
constexpr index_t<0> x{};
constexpr index_t<1> y{};

struct Vector {
    int data[2];

    template <size_t I>        
    int& operator->*(index_t<I> ) { return data[I]; }

    int& operator[](size_t idx) { return data[idx]; }
};
```

With that, we can do:

```
int main()
{
    Vector v{1, 2};
    std::cout << v.data[0] << ' ' << v.data[1] << '\n'; // 1 2
    v->*x = 42;
    v->*y = 17;
    std::cout << v.data[0] << ' ' << v.data[1] << '\n'; // 42 17
}
```

---

That said, don't do this. C++ doesn't have properties. The right way to do this would just be named functions that return lvalue references:

```
int& x();
int& y();
```

It may not be as "nice" as `v.x` but it gets the job done without having to add extra members to your class.

Comment: Wow, that's kinda funky. I really like how you could do a bunch of aliases for the operator to take. But it is rough as you couldn't use x or y again unless you dealt with hierarchy black magic. And a strange operator, as `v` is not a pointer. Summarizing, black evil voodoo! Quite curious.

Comment: As noone has given me a proper solution (if there's any) to my question, I'll be aproving your answer as, even if it's the same I said in the question, you gave me some thought-food.

Answer (score 0):

`v.x = 2.f` is not the OOP/C++ way of member access.  You are best off using get/set function like `t = v.x()` and `v.x( t )`.

It is possible to defeat the data encapsulation using the following:

```
template< class T >
class Vertex2 : private Vertex< T, 2 >
{
public:
   T & x;
   T & y;
   Vertex2(): Vertex< T, 2 >(), x((*this)[0]), y((*this)[1]) {}
};
```

This doesn't provide a `const` access but if you want to do `v.x =` you probably don't care too much about such things.  Unfortunately, you are probably stuck with the extra memory of the two references.

Comment: Two references could add up a bunch of memory in a, say, 10e3 array of vertices. Also, what would be better, `v.x(value)` or `v.x() = value` for a simple Data Object like a vertex, which behaves kinda like a struct (public members)?

Comment: I always use `v.x(value)`. This allows you to later do checks on the assigned value or more easily change the underlying implementation. For example if you are thinking of storing the Vertex objects in a container and doing sequential operations then using a VertexContainer with arrays for the x, y etc values will be substantially faster (2-3x). In that case Vertex might just be a glorified iterator into the VertexContainer.